# How to influence where a table cell get's split with iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText 2.1.7.

I like to influence where a table cell get's split. So e.g. if the word example-adress@123server.com is in the cell but the width of the cell requires splitting the string in three, then I'd like to tell iText somehow to split it like this "example-", "adress", "123server.com"

How can I do this?

Comment: I found this jar file, and the Hyphen related classes in the source code, but I do not yet know how to configure iText right to use it. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/i/Downloaditexthyphxmljar.htm

Comment: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/HyphenationExample

Comment: The moment people see iText 2.1.7, they know that they can skip the question. iText 2.1.7 dates from 2009. It's obsolete, unsupported and it has known technical and legal issues. Please upgrade to a more recent version of iText.

Comment: A major issue I am having with the later versions is that there is no price information at the website unless filling out a form.

Comment: Pricing depends on your use. Are you building a SaaS service? Are you deploying iText on a single server? Are you building a product? We used to have pricing information on the site, but people found it confusing. Some said: how expensive: about $2000 for a single server. Other said: how cheap: about $20 for a server. Both prices were right in their very specific context, but you won't get a server license for $20 if you're using iText on a single server, nor do you need to pay $2000 per server if you're creating a product that is sold to hundreds of customers.

Comment: All in all, saying "I have to fill out a form" is a lame excuse. You aren't doing your customers a service by using iText 2.1.7.